# Снизить нагрузку на сайт

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. На днях запустил сайт. После тестов. Заметил, что сайт создает такую нагрузку:
10 человек на сайте.
Сайт - это есть сервис (приложение). Люди просматривают по 20-30 страниц после входа на сайт.

Нагрузка на CPU: 0.62 cp
Нагрузка на MySQL: 1 (единица).

Плохо разбираюсь с нагрузками поэтому и спрашиваю.
Пока что кеширую на главной странице только половину данных с базы.

Как можно снять нагрузку на CPU.

Так же сразу, подскажите с такой ситуацией:

Имеется header он неизменный и он вставляется на каждую страницу. В этом header'е есть счетчик, который динамически показывает количество оповещений. При загрузке страницы он делает запрос, если же кешировать, то не узнать, пришло ли новое оповещение. Есть вариант: при каждом действие, который изменяет счетчик оповещений чистить кеш пользователя, у которового этот счетчик оповещения. Есть ли альтернативы или он самый оптимальный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Много вариантов.

1. Статику всю (картинки, медиа-файлы и прочее) вынести с сервера динамики (см. nginx) - это освободит канал и снимет нагрузку с апача.
2. Поднимите мемкэш и всё, что получаете из БД - пишите туда.
3. "при каждом действие, который изменяет счетчик оповещений чистить кеш пользователя" - да, Ваш вариант верный, просто сбрасывайте кэш при обновлении данных в БД и при следующем селекте пишите данные в кэш;
4. Почитайте про slow queries (ну и mysql_slow_log), а также про индексы. Ну и про explain запросов конечно :)

И да, "10 человек на сайте" и тормоза - это значит у Вас всё очень плохо с перечисленными мною пунктами, одни только индексы могут дать огромный прирост в производительности.

И да, ещё, конечно, хостинг играет важную роль.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Воспользуюсь. 10 человек, который каждый из них в данную минуту переходит по 20-30 страниц за маленький промежуток времени. около 250 запросов к базе.

Comment: Посмотрите, какие запросы грузят БД (команда: "show processlist;") и сократите количество селектов до минимума.
То есть по-хорошему так:
1. проверяем, есть ли данные в кэше
2.1 есть - берем данные из кэша
2.2 нет - пишем данные в  кэш
3. отдаем данные

Если нужно очень быстро, то реализовать можно "в лоб": написать обертку для запросов к БД, если начинается с "SELECT", то делаем md5() запроса - это будет ключ кэширования. Дальше проверяем, есть ли в кэше данные с этим ключом, есть - отдаем, нет - берем данные и сохраняем в кэш.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все звучит очень хорошо, но в моем представление все глухо. Про ngix: Необходимо арендовать сервер и хранить всю медиа там?

Comment: > Необходимо арендовать сервер и хранить всю медиа там?
Как вариант. Но это будет иметь смысл при больших нагрузках (десятки тысяч хостов)

Comment: Не подскажите, лучше xCache использовать или memcached? Что и в чем лучше? Спасибо.

Comment: Это разные вещи.
memcache - для кэширования данных.
XCache - для кэширования скриптов.

По-хорошему, Вам и то, и то надо.

Comment: А разве нельзя использовать только memcache или XCache для кеширования данных и скриптов?